# Nest can't resolve dependencies of custom service

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, injectable

I am basically follow this tutorial with very minor modifications:[link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-a-modern-app-using-nestjs-mongodb-and-vuejs#toc-connecting-with-mongodb-database)

I am using nest 6.14.2 on node 12.10.0.
When running my app I get:

```
> recon-backend@0.0.1 start C:\Users\e5553079\Desktop\Node_Projects\recon-backend
> nest start

[Nest] 8324   - 02/10/2020, 9:28:21 AM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 8324   - 02/10/2020, 9:28:21 AM   [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +53ms
[Nest] 8324   - 02/10/2020, 9:28:21 AM   [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ReconQueryService (?). Please make sure that the argument ReconQueryModel at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If ReconQueryModel is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If ReconQueryModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ReconQueryModel */ ]
  })
 +2ms
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ReconQueryService (?). Please make sure that the argument ReconQueryModel at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.
```

My files look like this:

**1. app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ReconQueryModule } from './reconQuery/reconQuery.module';
import { ReconQueryService } from './reconQuery/reconQuery.service';
import { ReconQueryController } from './reconQuery/reconQuery.controller';
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/backend-app', { useNewUrlParser: true }),
    ReconQueryModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, ReconQueryController],
  providers: [AppService, ReconQueryService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**2. reconQuery.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ReconQuery } from './interfaces/reconQuery.interface';
import { CreateReconQueryDTO } from './dto/create-reconQuery.dto';

@Injectable()
export class ReconQueryService {
    constructor(@InjectModel('ReconQuery') private readonly reconQueryModel: Model<ReconQuery>) { }
    // Fetch all queries
    async getAllQueries(): Promise<ReconQuery[]> {
        const queries = await this.reconQueryModel.find().exec();
        return queries;
    }
...
```

**3. reconQuery.interface.ts**

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface ReconQuery extends Document {
    readonly id: number;
    readonly name: string;
    readonly sql: string;
}
```

**4. reconQuery.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ReconQueryController } from './reconQuery.controller';
import { ReconQueryService } from './reconQuery.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ReconQuerySchema } from './schemas/reconQuery.schema';
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'ReconQuery', schema: ReconQuerySchema }])
  ],
  controllers: [ReconQueryController],
  providers: [ReconQueryService]
})
export class ReconQueryModule {}
```

I wonder why it cries about ReconQuery**Model** as I do not have such an entity, just a ReconQuery interface.

Answer (score 3):

You have extra `ReconQueryService` provided in `AppModule`.

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ReconQueryModule } from './reconQuery/reconQuery.module';
import { ReconQueryService } from './reconQuery/reconQuery.service';
import { ReconQueryController } from './reconQuery/reconQuery.controller';
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/backend-app', { useNewUrlParser: true }),
    ReconQueryModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, ReconQueryController],
  providers: [AppService, ReconQueryService], // <-- this causes the error
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`@InjectModel()` is provided by calling `MongooseModule.forFeature(...)` on a certain `@Module()`. `ReconQueryService` in `ReconQueryModule` is fine because that's where you have `MongooseModule.forFeature()` called so `@InjectModel()` is provided properly. However, in `AppModule`, you don't have `MongooseModule.forFeature()` so **Nest** cannot resolve the `@InjectModel()` for `ReconQueryService`.

Check if you really need to use `ReconQueryService` in `AppModule` (services and controllers declared in `AppModule`). If you don't, then remove `ReconQueryService` from `providers` array. If you do, then go to `ReconQueryModule` and do the following:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ReconQueryController } from './reconQuery.controller';
import { ReconQueryService } from './reconQuery.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ReconQuerySchema } from './schemas/reconQuery.schema';
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'ReconQuery', schema: ReconQuerySchema }])
  ],
  controllers: [ReconQueryController],
  providers: [ReconQueryService],
  exports: [ReconQueryService] // <-- add this line
})
export class ReconQueryModule {}
```

**exported** things will be available to use outside of the module they're provided in. Just import that module somewhere else.